# Error:Execution failed for task app:processDebugResources

Tags: android, android-gradle-plugin

I get this following error when syncing android project with gradle:

```
Error:Execution failed for task ':app:processDebugResources'.
> com.android.ide.common.process.ProcessException: Failed to execute aapt
```

What does it mean? How do I fix it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First Clean Project and check that you have the latest build tools.(make sure to update support libraries to your current build tool version)

If error still exists Check if you added a resource that violates the conventions.
E.g. cannot have capital letters and such. eg : `file_name.PNG`
Or may be you rename a resource folder.In that case clear caches and restart!

Comment: Cleaning up the project solved the problem for me. Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

`processDebugResources` = You have resources (xml files, layouts, images, etc) that have errors or simply need rebuilt.

Cleaning the project may fix the error, but if not, there is often the actual error message within the Gradle console that tells which resource is the problem.

So, the solution to fixing it is usually to read what the full error says, not just the root exception.